# unreachable db container in a multi-container application - django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")

Tags: django, docker-compose, containers, microservices, centos8

All existing answers didn't solve this problem.

- I'm running two containers on a Linux machine using docker-compose.
- the db is up before the app (django).
- the db is accessible from "outer space" port... see pycharm data
  source connection snapshot.

  so, I think that the only reasonable suspect is the docker network. I
  think I had a similar problem when was trying to use docker containers
  to run word-press with it's db.

regarding the username I have changed all to my userid since the service was generating the db directory with systemd-coredump user.

```
(base) [liran@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/passwd
...
systemd-coredump:x:999:997:systemd Core Dumper:/:/sbin/nologin
liran:x:1000:1000::/home/liran:/bin/bash
...
```

[image]
**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
    - 8000:8000
    volumes:
    - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    user: 1000:1000
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    hostname: 'db'
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: admin
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33066:3306
    user: 1000:1000
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for pythonMS2 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'ij&p-fb=6#vn$n4c6*f@xna*yu9(ilf#j=4wg%o+1*+w*9_pi!'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'products'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pythonMS2.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pythonMS2.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'admin',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

requirements.txt

```
Django==3.1.3
djangorestframework==3.12.2
mysqlclient==2.0.1
django-mysql==3.9
django-cors-headers==3.5.0
pika==1.1.0
```

the containers:

```
(base) [liran@localhost pythonMS2]$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
18346ff80560        pythonms2_backend   "/bin/sh -c 'python …"   21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes       0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp    pythonms2_backend_1
20a481f42da0        mysql:5.7.22        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes       0.0.0.0:33066->3306/tcp   pythonms2_db_1
```

The Network:

```
(base) [liran@localhost pythonMS2]$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                          DRIVER              SCOPE
9fde7fdf60bd        bridge                        bridge              local
b13c58426fa4        host                          host                local
e6c6ca45026f        kafka-docker-master_default   bridge              local
db5f0b288d0b        mysql-net                     bridge              local
141d06d6193a        none                          null                local
52248a152d38        pythonms2_default             bridge              local

(base) [liran@localhost pythonMS2]$ docker network inspect 52248a152d38
[
    {
        "Name": "pythonms2_default",
        "Id": "52248a152d380f68c6964195c182617ebb82c9ada436faa9643e661417c4e066",
        "Created": "2021-06-01T20:33:38.25349467+03:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.48.0/20",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.48.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "18346ff805603cffc94916cddbae34fc8ebd415e8ad0e75d22d78af87f80227a": {
                "Name": "pythonms2_backend_1",
                "EndpointID": "7bb9679f9a50e0303b2fa058ce19d9e422c1d0d534c9bfccc4aec499329fa3c7",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:30:03",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.48.3/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "20a481f42da0549916677dc96e379d2358fce3320c90ce95c2ea9846b6e124d4": {
                "Name": "pythonms2_db_1",
                "EndpointID": "0fbfeb91c86cb2f2915d300b64019232cc32ac912082b4de9c15096c9872be59",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:30:02",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.48.2/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "pythonms2",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.25.0"
        }
    }
]
```

**Error Logs**

```
(base) [liran@localhost pythonMS2]$ docker logs 18346ff805603cffc94916cddbae34fc8ebd415e8ad0e75d22d78af87f80227a
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 459, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 216, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")

(base) [liran@localhost pythonMS2]$ docker logs 20a481f42da0549916677dc96e379d2358fce3320c90ce95c2ea9846b6e124d4
2021-06-01T17:34:21.414383Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2021-06-01T17:34:21.416110Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.22) starting as process 1 ...
2021-06-01T17:34:21.420323Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2021-06-01T17:34:21.420341Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-06-01T17:34:21.420346Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-06-01T17:34:21.420350Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2021-06-01T17:34:21.420353Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2021-06-01T17:34:21.420356Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-06-01T17:34:21.420633Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-06-01T17:34:21.420742Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2021-06-01T17:34:21.422405Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2021-06-01T17:34:21.433107Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-06-01T17:34:21.435318Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2021-06-01T17:34:21.447558Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2021-06-01T17:34:21.455285Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-06-01T17:34:21.455423Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-06-01T17:34:21.501838Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-06-01T17:34:21.502801Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2021-06-01T17:34:21.502817Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2021-06-01T17:34:21.503383Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.22 started; log sequence number 12360442
2021-06-01T17:34:21.503513Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2021-06-01T17:34:21.503707Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2021-06-01T17:34:21.504557Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210601 17:34:21
2021-06-01T17:34:21.507243Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2021-06-01T17:34:21.507512Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-01T17:34:21.510525Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2021-06-01T17:34:21.510907Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2021-06-01T17:34:21.510929Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2021-06-01T17:34:21.510956Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-06-01T17:34:21.513282Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2021-06-01T17:34:21.514124Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2021-06-01T17:34:21.514148Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2021-06-01T17:34:21.514158Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2021-06-01T17:34:21.514178Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2021-06-01T17:34:21.514182Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2021-06-01T17:34:21.514192Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2021-06-01T17:34:21.516142Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2021-06-01T17:34:21.516156Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2021-06-01T17:34:21.522253Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2021-06-01T17:34:21.522389Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.22'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by changing `bind-address` to `0.0.0.0` in the mysql config file (`/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` is the usual location)   inside the contaier.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. `[mysqld]
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir  = /var/lib/mysql
#log-error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
# By default we only accept connections from localhost
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0` yet I still get the same error message

Comment: @E Paul, any other idea?

Comment: I once used django + docker for multitenant purposes. This tutorial helped me a lot: https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-multi-tenant/en/latest/isolated-dockers.html . It uses postgres but everything should be the same if you change the db to mysql. It worked ok for me, try to look at the code and see if you're doing something different.

Answer (score 0):

On Centos8, The firewall is configured with nftables, which doesn't work well with docker.
To fix this problem, open fw configuration file:

```
sudo vim /etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf
```

Update FirewallBackend=nftables
to
**FirewallBackend=iptables**

save this change and reload firewalld:

```
sudo systemctl restart firewalld.service
```

Comment: Additionally, I was missing one comma on the MIDDLEWARE part in setting.py